# How to compute the overall mean for several files in R?

Tags: r

I have 365 files for one year`(considered as matrix with nrows=500 and ncol=700)` that I want to compute the overall mean of that year.

to read one files:

```
con <- file("C:\\Users\\data.img","rb")
dat<- readBin(con, numeric(), size=4,  n=700*500, signed=TRUE)
```

> str(dat)
>    num [1:810438] 0.5 0.2 0.1...

to read all files:

```
     dir1<- list.files("C:\\Users\\datsets", "*.img", full.names = TRUE)
```

to loop thru files:

```
       for (.files in seq_along(dir1)){
     file1 <- readBin(dir1[.files], numeric(), size = 4, n = 700*500, signed = T)}
```

any idea please on how to compute the mean of all values (pixel by pixel)so end up with one file with mean values?

Edit: I forgot to mention, I only want to compute the mean among elements (pixels) that have a positive value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two methods I can think of:

1) Using a `for` loop (memory efficient):

```
sum.dat <- rep(0, 810438)
sum.pos <- rep(0, 810438)
for (.file in dir1) {
   dat <- readBin(.file, numeric(), size = 4, n = 700*500, signed = TRUE)
   pos <- dat >= 0
   sum.dat <- sum.dat + dat * pos
   sum.pos <- sum.pos + pos
}
mean.dat <- sum.dat / sum.pos
```

2) Using `vapply` (concise code but not memory efficient as it loads all the data into memory at once. This might be what you want though if you plan to do further processing on all the data.)

```
dats <- vapply(dir1, readBin, FUN.VALUE = numeric(810438),
               what = numeric(), size = 4, n = 700*500, signed = TRUE)
mean.dat <- rowmeans(ifelse(dats >= 0, dats, NA), na.rm = TRUE)
```